# Create a dropdown list in the admin panel for a module

Tags: module, administrator

I have written a small and simple bootstrap carousel module. Articles having a specific category will be shown in this module. I'm wondering how to add a dropdown list in the admin panel to select another category.

Look at the image below. I'd like to add a dropdown of all categories there.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your module XML file, add the following:

```
<config>
    <fields name="params">
        <fieldset name="basic">
            <field name="mycategory" type="category" extension="com_content" label="Select a category" description="" />
        </fieldset>
    </fields>
</config>
```

`type="category"` is one of the default Joomla form fields that will pull all categories from the extension you specify, which in the case above, will pull them from `extension="com_content"`

Hope this helps

Comment: Awesome, thx. Where is the information of the selected value stored so I can use it in my helper.php?

Comment: It's stored in the database like all other parameter values. Have read through the Joomla documentation for getting module parameters and ask a new question if you run into any issues